# Customization of Table of Contents in amsbook Class

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tocloft, amsbook

Is it possible to customize the **table of contents** as per the  attached screen shot ? The following are required.

1. Chapter Name and Page Numbers in Red Color
2. Section Name and Page Numbers in Blue Color
3. Dots between chapter / section title and page numbers

Here is the code that needs to be customized.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
    \usepackage{xpatch,fmtcount}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
    \renewcommand{\sectionname}{Unit}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
    \makeatletter
    % remove the period from the toc
    \renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{%
    \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1 #2\quad}}#3} % was #2.\quad
    \let\tocchapter\tocsection
    \let\tocsubsection\tocsection
    \let\tocparagraph\tocsection
    \let\tocsubparagraph\tocsection
    % remove the period from the section numbers
    \renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{%
    \protect\textup{\protect\@secnumfont
    \csname the#1\endcsname
    \protect\enspace % was \@secnumpoint
    }%
    }
    % remove the period after the titles
    \patchcmd{\@sect}{\@addpunct.}{}{}{}
    % fix the page style
    \def\ps@headings{\ps@empty
    \def\@evenhead{%
    \setTrue{runhead}%
    \normalfont\scriptsize
    \hfil % <---- was \rlap{\thepage}\hfil
    \def\thanks{\protect\thanks@warning}%
    \leftmark{}{}\hfil}%
    \def\@oddhead{%
    \setTrue{runhead}%
    \normalfont\scriptsize \hfil
    \def\thanks{\protect\thanks@warning}%
    \rightmark{}{}\hfil}% <--- was \hfil\llap{\thepage}
    % taken from \ps@plain
    \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\scriptsize \hfil\thepage\hfil}%
    \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    %
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\partmark{\@secmark\markboth\partrunhead\partname}%
    \def\chaptermark{%
    \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
    \def\sectionmark{%
    \@secmark\markright\sectionrunhead\sectionname}%
    }
    \makeatother
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{chapter}}-\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{section}: }}
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{First}
    \section{one}
    \chapter{Second}
    \section{two}
    \section{three}
    \chapter{Third}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: b]

This is the code for the three requirements.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{xpatch,fmtcount}
\usepackage{xcolor} % added

\usepackage{hyperref} %changed to control the colors in TOC
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\makeatletter
\global\def\param{} 
% color of page numbers in TOC <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\@tocpagenum}[1]{\hss{\mdseries\ifx\param\empty\color{red}\else\color{blue}\fi #1}}

\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{% style of section in TOC <<<<<<<<<<
\global\def\param{section} \color{blue}
\indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1\;#2\;}}#3\dotfill} % spaces, color and dots

\renewcommand{\tocchapter}[3]{%% style of chapter in TOC <<<<<<<<<<
\global\def\param{}\color{red}
\indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1\;#2\enspace}}#3\dotfill} % spaces,color and dots

\let\tocsubsection\tocsection
\let\tocparagraph\tocsection
\let\tocsubparagraph\tocsection

\renewcommand{\sectionname}{Unit}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}

% remove the period from the section numbers
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{%
    \protect\textup{\protect\@secnumfont
        \csname the#1\endcsname
        \protect\enspace % was \@secnumpoint
    }%
}

% remove the period after the titles
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\@addpunct.}{}{}{}
% fix the page style
\def\ps@headings{\ps@empty
    \def\@evenhead{%
        \setTrue{runhead}%
        \normalfont\scriptsize
        \hfil % <---- was \rlap{\thepage}\hfil
        \def\thanks{\protect\thanks@warning}%
        \leftmark{}{}\hfil}%
    \def\@oddhead{%
        \setTrue{runhead}%
        \normalfont\scriptsize \hfil
        \def\thanks{\protect\thanks@warning}%
        \rightmark{}{}\hfil}% <--- was \hfil\llap{\thepage}
    % taken from \ps@plain
    \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\scriptsize \hfil\thepage\hfil}%
    \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    %
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\partmark{\@secmark\markboth\partrunhead\partname}%
    \def\chaptermark{%
        \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
    \def\sectionmark{%
        \@secmark\markright\sectionrunhead\sectionname}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{chapter}}-\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{section}:}}% extra space removed <<<<
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{First}
    \section{one}
    \chapter{Second}
    \section{two}
    \section{three}
    \chapter{Third}
\end{document}
```